# Downtime on VPS because of Memory leak?

Tags: mysql, apache, memory, vps

I recently noticed that my server has a downtime for about 10 minutes and it gets up and running again. I checked the kill process logs and it was due to an OOM error which simply means it was out of memory. I installed atop on the server to have more detailed logs from when this happens next time.

Here are the atop logs that highlighted in red:

```
MEM |  tot     1.9G |  free   73.8M |  cache  28.5M |  dirty   0.0M |  buff    0.6M |  slab   69.0M  | shmem  15.7M  | shrss   0.0M  | vmbal   0.0M  | hptot   0.0M  | hpuse   0.0M  |
SWP |  tot     1.0G |  free   21.8M |               |               |               |                |               |               |               | vmcom   3.4G  | vmlim   2.0G  |
PAG |  scan 25837e4 |  steal 1143e3 |  stall      8 |               |               |                |               |               |               | swin    6896  | swout  56562  |
DSK |           vda |  busy    101% |  read  170294 |  write  14199 |  KiB/r     48 |  KiB/w     54  |               | MBr/s   13.5  | MBw/s    1.3  | avq   122.74  | avio 3.25 ms  |
```

Also I checked the memory usage by each process at that time and the logs are as follows:

```
PID     TID    MINFLT    MAJFLT    VSTEXT    VSLIBS     VDATA    VSTACK     VSIZE    RSIZE     PSIZE     VGROW     RGROW    SWAPSZ    RUID        EUID         MEM    CMD       1/55

 26092      -     16219      1084    11960K     4176K      1.3G      132K  1.3G   291.0M    292.7M     2904K     -0.2G    179.4M    mysql       mysql        15%    mysqld
 1676       -     93199      1108     3740K    24512K    177.1M      132K    483.8M   106.1M    103.1M    483.8M    106.1M     1860K    outdoorf    outdoorf      5%    php-fpm
 1720       -     36564       595     3740K    24492K    98932K      132K    401.3M   99616K    97006K    401.3M    99616K     1920K    purplelo    purplelo      5%    php-fpm
 1686       -     78360       818     3740K    24492K    96932K      132K    399.3M   98056K    95195K    399.3M    98056K     1896K    outdoorf    outdoorf      5%    php-fpm
 1411       -       325         7        8K    15992K    96904K      132K    239.1M   97632K    56978K        0K    -1464K        0K    root        root          5%    spamd child
  897       -      1503       133        8K    15316K    96004K      132K    223.6M   96860K    55952K        0K    -2904K        0K    root        root          5%    spamd
 1643       -    110669       467     3740K    24512K    161.1M      132K    467.8M   92732K    89822K    467.8M    92732K     1916K    outdoorf    outdoorf      5%    php-fpm
 1672       -    100116       529     3740K    24492K    88936K      132K    391.5M   90276K    87441K    391.5M    90276K     1924K    outdoorf    outdoorf      4%    php-fpm
 1694       -     78190       497     3740K    24512K    157.9M      132K    464.6M   89352K    86315K    464.6M    89352K     1984K    outdoorf    outdoorf      4%    php-fpm
 1710       -     52865      1580     3580K    21664K    72368K      132K    362.3M   70348K    68423K    362.3M    70348K     2160K    build2      build2        3%    php-fpm
 1738       -     20304       810     3740K    24492K    64080K      132K    367.3M   64592K    61803K    367.3M    64592K     1996K    purplelo    purplelo      3%    php-fpm
 1680       -     99040       702     3740K    24512K    133.1M      132K    439.8M   63824K    60884K    439.8M    63824K     1872K    newrossc    newrossc      3%    php-fpm
1675       -    123238       851     3740K    24512K    128.1M      132K    434.8M   58972K    55960K    434.8M    58972K     1912K    newrossc    newrossc      3%    php-fpm
 1755       -     15669       187     3740K    24492K    47548K      132K    351.1M   47696K    44883K    351.1M    47696K     1896K    newrossc    newrossc      2%    php-fpm
 1757       -     14882       212     3740K    24492K    44972K      132K    348.6M   45172K    42381K    348.6M    45172K     1896K    newrossc    newrossc      2%    php-fpm
 1722       -     28358       477     3580K    21664K    43328K      132K    333.9M   41208K    39268K    333.9M    41208K     2144K    build2      build2        2%    php-fpm
 1721       -     28301       435     3580K    21664K    43328K      132K    333.9M   41204K    39264K    333.9M    41204K     2148K    build2      build2        2%    php-fpm
 1723       -     28301       410     3580K    21664K    43328K      132K    333.9M   41196K    39259K    333.9M    41196K     2152K    build2      build2        2%    php-fpm
1724       -     28448       391     3580K    21664K    43328K      132K    333.9M   41180K    39243K    333.9M    41180K     2168K    build2      build2        2%    php-fpm
 1759       -     11336       192     3740K    24492K    34684K      132K    338.6M   35524K    32677K    338.6M    35524K     1912K    c558571     c558571       2%    php-fpm
 1756       -     11273       198     3740K    24492K    34768K      132K    338.6M   35344K    32497K    338.6M    35344K     1912K    c558571     c558571       2%    php-fpm
 1773       -      7225       175     3740K    24492K    23332K      132K    327.5M   23628K    20754K    327.5M    23628K     2208K    newrossc    newrossc      1%    php-fpm
 1774       -      6850        99     3740K    24492K    21132K      132K    325.3M   21200K    18471K    325.3M    21200K     2156K    purplelo    purplelo      1%    php-fpm
 1175       -        85         6      540K    11800K    234.2M      132K    303.3M   21172K    21366K        0K     -768K    86452K    named       named         1%    named
 1781       -      6634        86     3740K    24492K    20932K      132K    325.1M   21036K    18308K    325.1M    21036K     2152K    purplelo    purplelo      1%    php-fpm
1776       -      6832        71     3740K    24492K    20932K      132K    325.1M   20988K    18289K    325.1M    20988K     2152K    purplelo    purplelo      1%    php-fpm
 1775       -      2117       208      196K     6212K    16304K      132K    70004K   11192K     8312K    70004K    11192K     6080K    root        root          1%    tailwatchd - c
```

I googled the problem and I tried to set a memory limit on each website but it didn't help. I am using WordPress on every site on this server. It seems like something is causing a huge memory spike but I don't really know why. Did you guys have the same problem? How did you go about solving it?

Comment: This would be a better question suited for https://superuser.com or https://serverfault.com

Comment: memory leak? i think MySQL uses that much resources because of badly written or badly optimized qeuries..  Use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in cobination with `EXPLAIN <query>` on MySQL the next time if it happens again and if you can connect to the VPS..

Comment: Perhaps 2 Gigabyte of RAM just isn't enough for the number of Wordpress sites, with plugins, you're running?